# Join Merge only the first two lines of a file using AWK or SED

Tags: join, awk, sed, merge, lines

I have a file like this

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

I need the output like this:

```
Line1Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

I tried **sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g" asd.txt** but it combines all lines into one.

Comment: You are changing all the lines ,just specify the first line like this `sed ":a;1N;$!ba;s/\n//g" asd.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed 'N;0,/\n/s/\n//' file
Line1Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

`N` appends the next line into pattern-space. `0,/./` (specifies the range) which helps to do the replacement on the first match only. `s/\n//` replaces the first newline character with an empty string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Maybe some people just have a bad day and down vote good answers. (Now i could say: Merry Christmas, which is a bit late or Happy new year which is a but early :D)

Answer (score 3):

An awk solution would be like

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR==1?"":"\n")}1 ' input
Line1Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

**OR**

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR==1?"":RS)}1 ' input
Line1Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

Comment: ++ for parenthesizing the ternary op. Minor nitpick - you can save 2 chars by using `RS` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: @jaypalsingh `RS` is a good choice. Added in answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` you can restrict an operation to a [specific line number](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-26). In this case, we are restricting the append (to pattern space) and substitution to line 1:

```
sed '1 {N; s/\n//}' file
```

Note that this solution could also be written without the braces:

```
sed '1N; s/\n//' file
```

But please note that this last solution is somewhat less maintainable. Whether or not that's problematic for you is another thing. In either case, the results are:

```
Line1Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

Comment: This answer is correct. However as often may happen the solution may be amended to apply new specifications and the *dangling* `s/\n//` will perhaps catch out the unwary. For this reason it is probably best to group the two commands and apply them to the address. At least this will draw the attention of the programmer who comes after.

Comment: @potong: A fair point, and I've updated the solution to suit. It is hard to argue the case for not including the braces, but since the solution was going to be a short one, I thought I'd make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1 {N;s/\n//}'
```

results

```
Line1Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

take line 1 and add the next line to it . Afterwards remove the newline character